# Passing parameters into Guard Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

I have an app that I have setup with an Authentication Guard to make sure users cannot access the app unless they have logged in, like so

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    CanActivate, Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthContext } from './auth-context.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
        constructor(private router: Router, private authContext: AuthContext) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        // Check to see if a user has a valid JWT
        if (this.authContext.userInfo !== undefined && this.authContext.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
            // If they do, return true and allow the user to load the home component
            return true;
        }

        // If not, they redirect them to the login page
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }
}
```

I want to add another guard for Authorization that will check if the user is in a certain role. Currently I am hiding the link in navigation based on this role.

```
 <div *ngIf="userInRole('Admin')">
             This is secret stuff
 </div>
```

But if a user knows a route, they can just plug it into the url. How would I add my "userInRole()" type functionality to a Guard? I would have to pass the role name and do the check in code. Do Guards support params?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719445/pass-parameter-into-route-guard

Answer (score 13):

I found solution this

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { AuthService } from './service/auth.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class IsInRoleGuard implements CanActivate {
        constructor(
            private _authService: AuthService
        ) { }

        async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
            const userRole = this._authService.getRole(); // Get role from service
            if (next.data['roles'].indexOf(userRole) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and in your router-config

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RootComponent } from './root/root.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { IsInRoleGuard } from '../../guards/is-in-role.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: RootComponent, children: [
            {
                path: '', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [IsInRoleGuard], component: DashboardComponent, data: {
                    roles: [
                        'admin',
                        'super-admin'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const RouterConfig: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Answer (score 4):

A guard is just a class that implements CanActivate or CanDeactivate. But nothing stops you from injecting a service (or a value) that would return you the role of the user. For example,

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
        constructor(private router: Router, private authContext: AuthContext, 
             private user: MyUserService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
          if (!this.user.isAdmin()) return false;
          ...

    }
}
```