# How to return value for route guard from router event subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, router

I am trying to implement a secure route based on the right of the user. A user who doesn't have a specific right can't access that route. That's why I am passing the Right Name in a route (lazy module routing). But, I found that it's a bit complicated to get lazy route data. I had to subscribe to router events. But, after subscribing I am not finding a way to return false or true to Canactivate.

Here is my canActivate code:

```
 canActivate() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map((route) => {
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }
          return route;
        }),
        mergeMap((route) => route.data))
      .subscribe((event) => {
        const right = event.right; // getting the right name from the route data. 
        const rights = this.localStorageService.getLocalStorageItem('rights');

        if (right) {
          if (rights.includes(right)) {
            // I need to return true from here 
          } else {
            // I need to return false from here 
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

And, this is my route code:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: ':id', component: ProfileComponent, 
data: { right: 'VIEW_PROFILE' }, canActivate: [RightRouteGuardService]}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Angular route guard can return `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`. I think you want to return a boolean but if I were you in this case, I would return `Observable<boolean>`.

Try this:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => !!event), // !! add this filter !!
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map((route) => {
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }
          return route;
        }),
        mergeMap((route) => route.data),
        // map will return true false for us
        map(event => {
          const right = event.right; // getting the right name from the route data. 
          const rights = this.localStorageService.getLocalStorageItem('rights');
          if (right) {
            if (rights.includes(right)) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }
        }),
      );
}
```

You don't need to subscribe anymore, just the first emission from this observable will return the true and false for you.

========================= Edit ==========================
Don't inject the router and listen to the events because the router has not completed navigation yet and your `filter` of `NavigationEnd` will not allow it to proceed as well as there are no events at that moment in time.

I have solved the problem like so:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  CanActivate,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class RightRouteGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean{
    let right = route.data.right;
    console.log({ right });
    const rights = ['VIEW_STUDENT'];
    if (rights.includes(right)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

The `canActivate` method takes two properties and you can use the properties to read the data property of the route in question.

I got inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721468/7365461).

Comment: If I don't subscribe the event is showing undefined and the code is just stuck there. 
In this line the event is undefined. filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),

Comment: Check out my edit with `!! add this filter !!` to filter out the undefined emission.

Comment: Still not working. I have created a stackblitz. Can you check please if you have time- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-right?file=src/app/features/student/student-routing.module.ts

Comment: Yes, because it got stuck on right-route-guard.service.ts. That's what I was saying about getting undefined and stuck. You can debug from devtools

Comment: Check out my edit, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231217/discussion-between-shofol-and-alif50).

Comment: I'm trying to use this answer (it's first part) and I wonder, why the ```map((route) =>``` part is never called, at least on my side (tried with breakpoint and ```console.log```). Could you try to help me with this? Interesting is that when I subscribe, the subscription is called without any problem.

Comment: @Frimlik If you subscribe, and it goes inside of the `map` but not when you don't subscribe, I am thinking the configuration of `canActivate: [ThisGuard]` is wrong or the routing configuration is wrong. I am not entirely sure.

Comment: My previous comment was a little misleading. I then found your note after edit - as you pointed out, "there are no events at that moment", so there is no event to catch, so neither pipe nor subscribe are called.
I tried (just for fun) to return ```true``` from canActivate and was surprised that ```pipe``` and ```subscribe``` "started working"...

Comment: @Frimlik, ok, interesting. I think the `subscribe` happens at a later point in time after the `canActivate` returns `true`.