# Pass data to angular Guard CanActivateChild

Tags: javascript, angular

I actually got multiple guard which share the same exact data called from my API.

My guards look like that :

```
export class GuardBlockAgent implements CanActivateChild {
 ...

 canActivateChild(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

        return this.userService.retrieveMyUser(null, environment.liveMode).map(
        ...
    )}
```

I am looking for a way to share my data between my guards. Instead of making multiple call for the same data.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719445/pass-parameter-into-route-guard) they use this way with `canActivate`

> ```
> { 
>   path: 'super-user-stuff', 
>   component: SuperUserStuffComponent,
>   canActivate: RoleGuard,
>   data: {roles: ['SuperAdmin', ...]}
> }
> ```

But how to pass dynamic data which comes from my API ?

**theme-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        "path": "",
        "component": ThemeComponent,
        "resolve": { me: AgentResolver },
        "canActivate": [AuthGuard],
        "children": [
            {
                "path": "...",
                "loadChildren": "...",
                "canActivateChild": [GuardBlockAgent]
            },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ThemeRoutingModule { }
```

EDIT: localStroage are not safe, that's why I prefer not to use it.

Comment: what is wrong with using a `constructor` in your guard and inject some state service ?

Comment: Loading time, it is getting to long. I'd rather make the call once instead of X calls

Comment: You can create a root-level facade service for `userService`. It should cache the user and any other relational data.

Comment: Any exemple of what it looks like ? I've never heard of it

Comment: @crg I posted an answer and created a stackBlitz example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a facade layer for your `UserService`. The layer stores your user for runtime and it will not send requests to the server if data exist.

Check the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxswrf?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example. (Check console)

To create it;

**Step 1:** Create a facade service.

*user-service.facade.ts*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserServiceFacade extends UserService {
  private readonly user$ = new BehaviorSubject<{ name: string } | null>(null);

  retrieveMyUser(): Observable<{ name: string }> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      startWith(this.user$.value),
      switchMap(user => (user ? of(user) : this.getUserFromServer())),
      take(1)
    );
  }

  private getUserFromServer() {
    return super.retrieveMyUser().pipe(tap(user => this.storeUser(user)));
  }

  private storeUser(user: { name: string }): void {
    this.user$.next(user);
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** Override the dependency injection of the `UserService` token.

*app.module.ts or wherever you provided `UserService`*

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: UserService,
      useClass: UserServiceFacade
    }
  ],
```

And it is done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not see how it can help me sharing data between my guards. Maybe I didn't get how you use it. If you may show me how it would work in a guard it would be nice. I've done what you did in the stackBlitz but it doesn't change anything... I still have multiple call when using my guards

Comment: Actually in your exemple on  stackBlitz the UserServiceFacade is not needed to make it work. It seems that your entire UserServiceFacade is useless ...

Comment: It is storing data and not sending requests if the user already exists. And this means you can call the `retrieveMyUser` method everywhere you want. If the user exists it returns the user immediately, If not, it sends a request and stores user data.  In `stackblitz` example, you can check the console. It is logging while sending a request to retrieve the user.  @crg Moreover, if you need a more complicated solution, you can check `state management` libraries like ngrx or ngxs etc.

Comment: Seems like I was doing something the wrong way, it works fine. When I get to a new page and call the guard it does not make the call again. Thanks again for your help !