# How to restrict user to access unauthorized path in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, multi-user

In my Angular app has 3 types of users: admin, brewer (vendor) & end user. I want to prevent brewer from accessing admin routes, just as end users should be prevented from accessing admin routes and vendor route.

How I can achieve this through angular routing.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeContentComponent,
  },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: './modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'vendor',
    loadChildren: './modules/vendor/vendor.module#VendoreModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: './modules/user/user.module#UserModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  }
]
```

**Auth Guard :**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
  CanDeactivate,
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "../services/firebase/auth.service";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // Guard for userRole is login or not
    // var Role=localStorage.getItem('role')
    let user = localStorage.getItem('toke');
    if (!user) {
      this.router.navigate(["/auth/login"]);
      return true;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have auth guard like this how I can modify it to achieve desired functionality.

**It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help.**

Comment: In the `canActivate` property of a route, you can pass in multiple guards. Create the guards that you need and put them in the array, next to the `AuthGuard`. If you have already implemented the guards for vendor and normal user and they don't work as you expect them to, then include those in the body of your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass parameter into route guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719445/pass-parameter-into-route-guard)

Comment: Follow this https://www.geekstrick.com/angular-10-secure-routes-using-authguard-based-on-user-role/

Comment: Hey @Abhishek you're correct but marked solution seems easy to me that's why I choose that.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @konowo7640 there's easy and there's right. Picking easy will not get you far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have achieved this by using logic**,

You can use logic like in your **app.component.ts**

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
    
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
      ) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
          if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    
            const user = localStorage.getItem("Id");
            const Role = localStorage.getItem('UserRole')
            if (user && Role && Role === 'User' && ev.url.includes('/admin)) {
                this.router.navigate(['user/home']);
          }
        }
      }
```

> Similarly for your all roles you can define if condition and can
> redirect on their main route lets if user then user's default page,
> if super admin then it might be **admin/dashboard** anything like
> this.

**Second way:**

Another way to achieve this is to use [ngx-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions) using which you can control your route based on role.

attaching [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-permission-demo-qrji88) demo for more clarification.

[Official doc](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions#readme)

[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions)

Comment: This is **NOT** the proper way to do it (and should not be the accepted answer). The proper way is to use Guards. That's exactly what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with multiple if else condition

```
const Role = localStorage.getItem('role')
if(Role != "admin"){
    this.router.navigate(["/auth/login"]);
}
```