# How to test Functional Router Guard with Parameter within runInInjectionContext

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I'm implementing a [functional router guard](https://blog.angular.io/advancements-in-the-angular-router-5d69ec4c032#66d3) in Angular 15.2.9 which checks if a user is logged in. When this is not the case, the guard should return either `false` or a `UrlTree` (i.e. redirect to login page), depending on the parameter `redirectToLogin: boolean`.

I'm using a factory function for the functional route guard similar to the one in [this article](https://medium.com/ngconf/functional-route-guards-in-angular-8829f0e4ca5c#be6f):

```js
export const isLoggedIn = (redirectToLogin: boolean): CanActivateFn => {
  return (next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    const isLoggedIn = !!inject(CookieService).check('some_cookie');

    if (isLoggedIn) return true;
    if (!isLoggedIn && !redirectToLogin) return false;

    const redirectUrl = inject(Router).createUrlTree(['user', 'sign_in'], {
      queryParams: { next: encodeURIComponent(`/${next.url.join('/')}`) },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
    return redirectUrl;
  };
};
```

It works like expected but I am not able to write **specs** for it:

```js
  let cookieServiceSpy;
  let activatedRouteSnapshot;

  beforeEach(() => {
    cookieServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<CookieService>(['check']);
    activatedRouteSnapshot = { url: [], data: {} };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        isLoggedIn,
        { provide: CookieService, useValue: cookieServiceSpy },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          useValue: activatedRouteSnapshot,
        },
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should return true when secure_user_id cookie is present and redirectToLogin is false', () => {
    // given
    cookieServiceSpy.check.and.returnValue(true);
    activatedRouteSnapshot.data.redirectToLogin = false;
    // when
    const result = TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn); // <-- this line is the problem
    // then
    expect(result).toBeTrue();
  });
```

results in a typescript error: *Argument of type '(redirectToLogin: boolean) => CanActivateFn' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => CanActivateFn'.
Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.*

I tried several other options too:

- `TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn as any)` ➔ *Can't resolve all parameters for isLoggedIn: (?).* in test run
- `TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn(false))` ➔ *Argument of type 'CanActivateFn' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>'. Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 0.*
- `TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn(false) as any)` ➔ *Can't resolve all parameters for isLoggedIn: (?).* in test run
- `TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn(false)(activatedRouteSnapshot, null))` ➔ *Argument of type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => unknown'. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '() => unknown'.*
- `TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn(false)(activatedRouteSnapshot, null) as any);` ➔ *inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.*
- `TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn(false) as any)(activatedRouteSnapshot, null);`➔ *This expression is not callable. Type '{}' has no call signatures.*
- `(TestBed.runInInjectionContext(isLoggedIn(false) as any) as any)(activatedRouteSnapshot, null)` ➔ *Can't resolve all parameters for isLoggedIn: (?).*

I also tried omitting the factory function and using Route Data as parameter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74104082/2725515) but injecting `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is not possible and using `ActivatedRoute` results in nested Observables... there has to be an easier way.

**How can I test the functional router guard?**

Comment: Does it work if you remove `isLoggedIn` from your providers and just import it instead of using DI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are observing is due to 2 things :

- You provided a non-decorated symbol, `isLoggedIn`
- By calling `TestBed.runInInjectionContext`, you initilized the injector and the injector tried to convert the providers to factories which failed because `isLoggedIn` is not annotated and has 1 or more parameters (here only 1).

If you really needed to inject the `CanActivateFn` you could use `{provide: isLoggedIn, useValue: () => { ... }` but in our case you are not injecting the function, you're just calling it.

So no need to provide that function and the call is straight foward :

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    cookieServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<CookieService>(['check']);
    activatedRouteSnapshot = { url: [], data: {} };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: CookieService, useValue: cookieServiceSpy },
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should return true when secure_user_id cookie is present and redirectToLogin is false', async () => {
    // given
    cookieServiceSpy.check.and.returnValue(true);
    activatedRouteSnapshot.data.redirectToLogin = false;
    // when
    const result = TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => isLoggedIn(true)(activatedRouteSnapshot, undefined));  // Double call  to retrieve the result. 
    // then
    expect(result).toBeTrue();
  });
```